# Leveling the floor before vinyl

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I want to replace the vinyl flooring in the flat I bought, since the old one was full of bumps and bloated in some places. When I took the old one out, I noticed that it was very poorly done, with remannings of whatever was previously there.

So my question is, do I have to do anything before laying new on-click vinyl here? What would be the best and easiest way to scrape pieces and make the floor level?

[image: Current state of the subfloor]

[image: Current state of the subfloor]

[image: Current state of the subfloor]

[image: Current state of the subfloor]

Comment: what year was the place built?

Comment: Have you tried soaking the adhesive with water? Some  adhesives will soften with water and can then be scraped away.

Comment: It need not be level, just flat, which is much easier. Drag a board/ruler over it and scrape off any highpoints that create a fulcrum. I would also pour clay slip in any major divots to fill them securely.  Lastly, shell out for some underlayment like foil-backed foam, which gives all the tiny bumps some absorption margin before they lift up the rigid planks and generally makes the floor feel more secure and quiet.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't going to like this answer. The best way to do this, and I know from experience, is to get a floor scraper, like the one shown below, from your home store and go to town scraping the floor. You've got all sorts of stuff left over from previous floors and you need to remove all that if you want a quality job on the floor you're going to lay. Floor grinders or spreading solvents could work depending on the adhesives but in the long run, the scraper will do a better, cleaner job.

[image: ,]

Answer (score 0):

Remove any loose particle and organic residue.

Get self leveling concrete made for that purpose.

Apply it per instructions.

Usage:

At minimum thickness 1/8 of inch, aprox 48 sqft

[image: thickness]

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: I had friends do this, $18,000 (300 bags) later they had a nice flat floor for hardwood.  They used a professional hardwood floor installation company to do the leveling.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger 300 bags = 7,000 to 14,000 sqft ??? Now that is a home size !!

Comment: I think 4000 sq ft.  It really depends how out of level your floor is across your house.  If you go transition free and have 35' open span then you could be 2"-3" out over this distance.  If you further have some low spots and high spots and you decide the best approach is flood to the high then you are filling up to 5" everywhere except the high spot.

Comment: Seems that was an unfortunate decision on their part, @FreshCodemonger. The floor doesn't need to be level, just smooth!

Comment: @FreeMan wow, so all the floor leveling industry are just fakes ?

Comment: @freeman, this was high end hardwood installer's decision.  they typically go for flat but it seems like the industry practice is to flood up to the high spot and cover all the floor.  this makes sense from a training perspective as it isn't hard to mix or pour self level and then you are making sweet margin from each bag if you charge $60 a bag for install.  The SLC installer can then have virtually no training and you spend almost no time finding the low spots / high spots, no grinders required, very few power tools.  You do end up with a nice flat floor ready for hardwood too.